# Python library for downloading MP3 files from youtube

Tags: python-3.x, download, mp3

This is my first time on the forum so excuse me for not following conventions.

I'm trying to download mp3 files from youtube videos for music. I was wondering if there were any existing python libraries that could do this, by e.g:

searching youtube for the song OR accepting a string which it would search youtube for?

Thanks,
Matt.

Comment: Read This.. https://stackoverflow.com/a/23450086/5350773

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Revisiting this post since there seem to be many visits to my question recently. I re-did this project after a few years and ended up using [youtube-dl](https://youtube-dl.org/), which can be installed using the following command:

```sh
sudo pip install --upgrade youtube_dl
```

Answer (score 2):

I know of a github link to what you seek.
Visit this:-
https://github.com/mps-youtube/pafy

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am fairly new to this stuff, and I was wondering how you would install this as a library via command line?

Answer (score 1):

Indeed there is `pytube` for Python3.

Example Download of a audio file:

```
from pytube import YouTube

# creating YouTube object
yt = YouTube("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1csFTDXXULY") 

# accessing audio streams of YouTube obj.(first one, more available)
stream = yt.streams.filter(only_audio=True).first()
# downloading a video would be: stream = yt.streams.first() 

# download into working directory
stream.download()
```

Answer (score 1):

**Update 2022**
I no longer Maintains `mhyt` library.

you can try `youtube_dl` option:

To install:

```sh
pip install youtube_dl
# or for faster download and more improvements: 
#pip install yt-dlp
```

And use:

```py
from youtube_dl import YoutubeDL
# or for yt_dlp: 
# from yt_dlp import YoutubeDL
ydl_opts = {
    'format': 'm4a/bestaudio/best',
    'postprocessors': [{  # Extract audio using ffmpeg
        'key': 'FFmpegExtractAudio',
        'preferredcodec': 'mp3',
    }]
}
with YoutubeDL() as ydl:
   ydl.download(["https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0BVqFYParRs"])
```

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**:

> I have created a library that makes it simpler.
>
> To install:
>
> ```sh
> pip install mhyt
> # or $ sudo pip install mhyt
> ```
>
> And use it like:
>
> ```py
> from mhyt import yt_download file = "file.mp3" tmp_file =
> os.path.splitext(file)[0]+".webm"
> yt_download("url","file.format",ismucic=True)
> ```

Answer (score 0):

you can use pafy `pip install pafy` [pafy documentation](https://pythonhosted.org/pafy/)