# How download audio from youtube on kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, youtube

I need to download audio from any YouTube video in Kotlin for Android Studio, but I can't find any suggestions for accomplishing this task.

I need to download audio from any YouTube video in Kotlin for Android Studio. Thanks!

Comment: This is not permitted by the YouTube terms of service, I believe.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe some code snippets from this repo can help? https://github.com/nhcodes/iTube
or check out this link [Download ONLY audio from a youtube video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15241076/download-only-audio-from-a-youtube-video)
?
But it can be against the YouTube rules.